# AWS Amplify The variables input contains a field name that is not defined for input object type

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a series of forms that collects data into a form object, and on submit pushes that formdata to a dynamodb table via graphql query. For some reason I'm getting the following error.

```
The variables input contains a field name 'kidney infection' that is not defined for input object type 'CreateFormsInput'
```

I'm not sure what information is relevant to solving the issue, but here's my schema

```
type Forms @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  ...
  substances: [String]
  medications: [AWSJSON]
  condition_history: [AWSJSON]
  allergies: [AWSJSON]
  ...
}
```

and here's how I'm pushing

```
const formResponse = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createForms, { input: tempForm }));
```

When I'm building the form, the `condition_history` value is an object, but i do stringify it because that's what aws wants. An example value would be a stringified `{problem: "kidney infection"}`, turned into `"{\"problem\":\"kidney infection\"}"`. Of course, this is an array item, and multiple of these stringified objects can be in it.

And the thing is, I'm doing similar processes for things like `medications` and `allergies` but those aren't throwing any similar issues.

The issue does not persist if `condition_history` value is an empty array.

Am I missing something?

Edit to add more information.

The full(ish) createForm mutation autogenerated by graphql (adding ... to just cut out several irrelevant variables; just more of the same):

```
export const createForms = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateForms(
    $input: CreateFormsInput!
    $condition: ModelFormsConditionInput
  ) {
    createForms(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      facility_id
      ...
      medications
      condition_history
      ...
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

and the tempForm object that is sent to the API, also similarly trimmed to show relevant information:

```
{​
allergies: [ "{\"allergy\":\"\",\"details\":\"\"}" ],
...
condition_history: [ "{\"problem\":\"kidney infection\"}" ],
date_of_birth: "1966-01-04",
medications: [ "{\"medication\":\"\",\"dose\":\"\",\"frequency\":\"\"}" ]​,
smoking_history: "{\"has_smoked\":\"false\",\"currently_smokes\":\"\",\"cigarettes_per_day\":\"\",\"year_quit_smoking\":\"\"}",
}
```

and unstringified:

```
{
    ...
    "smoking_history": {
        "has_smoked": "false",
        "currently_smokes": "",
        "cigarettes_per_day": "",
        "year_quit_smoking": ""
    },
    "medications": [
        {
            "medication": "",
            "dose": "",
            "frequency": ""
        }
    ],
    "allergies": [
        {
            "allergy": "blah",
            "details": "sdsds"
        }
    ],
    "condition_history": [
        {
            "problem": "kidney infection"
        }
    ],
    "kidney infection": true #this might be the problem...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the requested type in the error message: CreateFormsInput

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Can I ask what you mean? The error message I posted is the whole thing.

Comment: Please show the value of the `tempForm` variable you are sending to your API as well as the definition of the `createForms` mutation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I've edited the post with some extra details. `condition_history` is the problem variable, but it's no different from the other stringified json arrays that seem to work fine when posted to the api. That's to say `condition_history` posts fine if it's an empty array.

Comment: Very odd because it thinks that `kidney infection` is a key instead of a value. Can you show `tempForm` *before* it is stringified? Hard to follow with all those escaped double quotes. What do you get if you `JSON.parse(tempForm)` ?

Comment: @MichelFloyd ah, i think i see the problem... I may be dumb. Check the edited post. Looks like there is a redundant key that's added to the json that i missed and forgot about. I'm assuming that if that key isn't defined in the schema it would throw this error?

Comment: We've all been there.